# escaping parenthesis for XSS

Tags: java, regex

I had an issue where I need to validate the username field to avoid XSS attack. I am validating the username with a regex pattern. We have a client whose username contains parenthesis ex:huy(). My regex pattern does not have parenthesis so validation is failing.  But here comes the main thing i.e when I add parenthesis to regex the validation passes but some of our security team is reporting XSS attack because of parenthesis.

So is there a way to allow parenthesis and at the same time to mitigate xss attack. Any help would be highly appreciated.

sample code:

```
String value="huy()";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z0-9._@~#\"\"])") ;
```

Comment: You wanted to allow empty `()` parenthesis as a userName? if that is the case then ideally you can use string contains function on top of pattern matching. This can considered an exceptional case.

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/O78mss/2) help?This will not allow only parenthesis; it should contain a word character.

Comment: Your pattern matches a single character. Are you validating each key stroke with that? You can't ensure the whole string validation if you go on using that.

Comment: Am just  checking whether the  all the characters in username is exactly matched with regex or not

Comment: It is still unclear. If you want to match exact username then you can use `str.equals()` method.Isn't it?

Comment: i can add those parenthesis in my regex but our security team reported XSS issue when we are allowing parenthesis

Comment: So; one workaround can be thought of. Since; cross-site vulnerabilities are client side vulnerabilities; you can accept the input from user without any parenthesis and at server side you can add them.